# Jest configuration are not supported by Create React App

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, stryker

I was setting up Stryker on my react app, but the error message appeared when I tried to run it --

These options in your package.json Jest configuration are not currently supported by Create React App:

.testResultsProcessor
.setupFiles

It suggested me to eject from the default setup, but I am looking for an alternative option.

Comment: Which node version are you using ? try node version 15.16.1 `nvm use 16.15.1`

Comment: I'm having exact the same problem. Is there already any solution for this?